# Swagger - Route defined in Swagger specification but there is no defined get operation

Tags: node.js, rest, web-services, swagger, swagger-ui

I am creating a nodejs web service using swagger-ui. So I went on the online editor of swagger, did my yaml and exported it for nodejs server.
When I am running in on my computer, with host as localhost (see yaml) I try to perform a PUT I got that message :

```
Error: Route defined in Swagger specification (/test) but there is no defined get operation.
    at send405 (/home/guillaume/Desktop/docker-swagger2-amp/node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-router.js:307:13)
    at swaggerRouter (/home/guillaume/Desktop/docker-swagger2-amp/node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-router.js:422:16)
    at call (/home/guillaume/Desktop/docker-swagger2-amp/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
    at next (/home/guillaume/Desktop/docker-swagger2-amp/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
    at swaggerValidator (/home/guillaume/Desktop/docker-swagger2-amp/node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-validator.js:409:14)
    at call (/home/guillaume/Desktop/docker-swagger2-amp/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
    at next (/home/guillaume/Desktop/docker-swagger2-amp/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
    at swaggerMetadata (/home/guillaume/Desktop/docker-swagger2-amp/node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-metadata.js:451:14)
    at call (/home/guillaume/Desktop/docker-swagger2-amp/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
    at next (/home/guillaume/Desktop/docker-swagger2-amp/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
```

and

```
Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8080/v2/test: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

I have a get operation so I don't know what is the error. Here are my main files :

**YAML:**

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about     Swagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).      For this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization     filters."
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "Swagger Petstore"
  termsOfService: "http://swagger.io/terms/"
  contact:
    email: "apiteam@swagger.io"
  license:
    name: "Apache 2.0"
    url: "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
basePath: "/v2"
tags:
- name: "test"
  description: "Define yours parameters launching"
schemes:
- "http"
paths:
  /test:
    put:
      tags:
      - "test"
      summary: "Add Test configuration and use it to launch Test"
      description: ""
      operationId: "addTestconf"
      consumes:
      - "application/xml"
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/xml"
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - in: "body"
        name: "body"
        description: "test configuration that needs to be used to run test"
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/test"
      responses:
        400:
          description: "Invalid ID supplied"
        404:
          description: "test not found"
        405:
          description: "Validation exception"
  /test/{TestId}:
    get:
      tags:
      - "test"
      summary: "Find Test config by ID"
      description: "Returns a Test config"
      operationId: "getTestConfigurationById"
      produces:
      - "application/xml"
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - name: "testId"
        in: "path"
        description: "ID of test config to return"
        required: true
        type: "integer"
        format: "int64"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "successful operation"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/test"
        400:
          description: "Invalid ID supplied"
        404:
          description: "test Config not found"


definitions: ........
```

**index.js:**

```
'use strict';

    var fs = require('fs'),
        path = require('path'),
        http = require('http')

    var app = require('connect')();
    var swaggerTools = require('swagger-tools');
    var jsyaml = require('js-yaml');
    var serverPort = 8080;

    // swaggerRouter configuration
    var options = {
      swaggerUi: path.join(__dirname, '/swagger.json'),
      controllers: path.join(__dirname, './controllers'),
      useStubs: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' // Conditionally turn on stubs (mock mode)
    };

    // The Swagger document (require it, build it programmatically, fetch it from a URL, ...)
    var spec = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'api/swagger.yaml'), 'utf8');
    var swaggerDoc = jsyaml.safeLoad(spec);

    // Initialize the Swagger middleware
    swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, function (middleware) {
      // Interpret Swagger resources and attach metadata to request - must be first in swagger-tools middleware chain
      app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());

      // Validate Swagger requests
      app.use(middleware.swaggerValidator());

      // Route validated requests to appropriate controller
      app.use(middleware.swaggerRouter(options));

      // Serve the Swagger documents and Swagger UI
      app.use(middleware.swaggerUi());

      // Start the server
      http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, function () {
        console.log('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
        console.log('Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:%d/docs', serverPort);
      });

    });
```

**and my controllers :**
**test_configuration.js:**

```
'use strict';

var url = require('url');

var test = require('./testService');

module.exports.addTestConf = function addTestConf(req, res, next) {
  test.addTestConf(req.swagger.params, res, next);
};

module.exports.getTestConfigurationById = function getTestConfigurationById(req, res, next) {
  test.getTestConfigurationById(req.swagger.params, res, next);
};
```

**test_configurationService.js:**

```
use strict';

exports.addTestConf = function(args, res, next) {
  res.end();
}

exports.getTestConfigurationById = function(args, res, next) {
  res.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The operationId must match the controller function.

Looks like there is a case mismatch in your code:

- operationId: addTestconf
- function name: addTestConf

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS related problem

if you try to request the Api using a different url/host than the indicated in .yaml file you'll get this error

so if in your .yaml you have

```
host: "localhost:8085"
```

and used 127.0.0.1:8080 you may face this issue.